# Connecting more than 2 devices together using Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am having a problem with a chatting app i am writing in Swift using Multipeer Connectivity. Getting 2 devices to share their sessions together seems to work no problem, however when I connect a 3rd, the application starts to do weird things.

For example: you have 3 devices; Device A, Device B & Device C.

I connect Device A to Device B, all is fine, both can talk to each other & share their profile (upon the 2 devices connecting to each other, they share the profile picture with each other).

I then connect Device A to Device C. They connect and more often than not will share profiles with each other. But then Multipeer Connectivity seems to want to share Device C's session to Device B's without the user asking, attempts to share profiles, then one of the devices (usually Device C in this example) will crash & close the app.

When Multipeer Connectivity runs the method, it runs to connect 2 devices sessions together. It appears to want to gather all connected user sessions from each device & attempt to connect either device to all connected users known to the opposite. Could anybody explain to me why Multipeer Connectivity would do this & if theres anyway to stop it doing this?

I do realise the MPC uses Mesh Networking to allow devices to communicate via other devices using a daisy-chained-style connection, but I don't see why they are sharing each others sessions. Surely it should only share sessions with the requested devices rather than everyone each are connected to?

Comment: i should mention that I am using the standard MCBrowserViewController as the menu to connect devices together

Comment: Can you post the crash?

Comment: i figured out why it was crashing. I am sending the senders MCPeerID & receivers MCPeerID with every message & profile that is sent for vaidation purposes. When it comes to sending the profile picture from a device to a device thats connected to a device (in this case, Device C to Device B), the MCPeerIDs being sent are both dead, causing a crash when it tries to validate the MCPeerIDs. putting nil checks stopped the application from crashing.

still, the issue is more getting MPC to only send data between the 2 devices that are connecting & not to their other connected devices also.

Comment: @RikStott If you solved the problem. Add the solution as an answer to the question and accept your answer.